# Using jQuery with Flush (aka jQuery script progress bar)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, flush

I have a long-running script that eventually outputs a file to be downloaded. What I'm trying to do is show a progress bar for that file.

Basically the logic should be:

1. Start looping through objects (can be thousands)
2. Echo a progress report every loop
3. Flush the buffer for output to show immediately
4. Use jQuery to check that content and display things accordingly

Problem is as I understand, jQuery's AJAX functions wait for the finished HTTP response (by design) so buffering won't help (as the success functions won't load until I finish completely).

How would I go about doing this? Only answers I've found are way outdated plugins that can't be found anymore.

And no - I don't mean a file *upload* status bar, but a script load one.

Comment: Take a look at web sockets and server sent events.

Comment: @Musa any link or reference?